# Конвертация py в ipa

Tags: python, ios

Можно ли как-то сделать файл в формате .ipa для iOS из файла в формате .py? Написал игру на pygame, можно ли ее как-нибудь перенести на ios?

Comment: Конечно можно, запусти свой скрипт через эту программу https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/python-3/id1262850648.

Comment: А вообще сами вопрос свой поняли?